# Need to understand the logic used in multiTransfer function,

Tags: transfer

```
* @notice Transfer tokens to multiple recipient
     * @dev Left 160 bits are the recipient address and the right 96 bits are the token amount.
     * @param bits array of uint
     * @return true/false
     */
    function multiTransfer(uint256[] memory bits) external returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
            address a = address(uint160(uint256(bits[i] >> 96)));
            uint256 amount = bits[i] & ((1 << 96) - 1);
            require(transfer(a, amount), "Transfer failed");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Can some please explain the logic of the function

Answer (score 2):

The logic is simple, You transfer the amounts of the token described by the contract this function is part of, to the addresses specified in the entry data.

The only different logic here is how are the address and amount encoded. here they are expected to be encoded in an `uint256` format with specific bits set for the address and the rest for the amount. The entry array is an array of bits each have both the address and amount.

the bits array should look something like this (the values are in hex but conversion to bits yields 1 and 0 characters)

```
bits = [101011110101010101010101010101111001, 101011110101010101010101010101111001]

for each bit in bits 
    address = bit.slice(0, 160)
    amount  = bit.slice(160, 256)
    success = transfer(address, amount)
    if(not success) throw("Transfer failed")
```

the `>>` and `<<` operators are meant for [shifting bits](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/cheatsheet.html?highlight=operator#order-of-precedence-of-operators), the first time we read the address from the left of the bit sequence the second time we read the amount starting from the right, so we use the opposite operator.

the last line is meant to verify if the transfer has failed or not. The transfer function would return a bool.

Comment: Souldn't it be : `address a = address(uint160(uint256(bits[i] >> 160)));`

Comment: Also , what is `&` and why `-1` in `uint256 amount = bits[i] & ((1 << 96) - 1);`

Comment: @Ashishkumar the & and -1 are to prepend Zeros to the amount. i don't know why is that is necessary but the whole idea is just them extracting address and amount from a set of brits.